# Is it possible to use a Proxy JavaScript Object to 'trap' a user from finding its properties/values by emptying the Object PRIOR to getting info/data?

Tags: javascript, object, es6-proxy

said simply:

I am trying to create a protective barrier around a JavaScript Object, using a Proxy to set 'traps' for any form of retrieval or manipulation. These traps will require the SessionKey parameter to be provided with any such Object manipulations or else default into clearing out -all- information and properties of the Object.

(This SessionKey is of course the one provided by the User Sign-in PHP which is sent back upon successful sign-in.)

If I have this right, and I'm not the most veteran coder here certainly, the Object will only call functions with the corresponding SessionKey parameter being provided - as this Object knows the SessionKey.

I cannot be 100% to thwart any or all such efforts to get into my code, but perhaps I can set up a 'trip' alarm that makes all such efforts unsuccessful. No SessionKey? NO DOM (.empty()), no WebServices/API. Nothing.

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: using a Proxy on the clientside does not prevent that all the information get sent to the client, and therefore they can easily be read out in the network requests tab of the browsers developer tools. Instead you have to filter out those information on the serverside. Proxies won't help you at all.

Comment: I understand that the network activity can be snooped. I hope to find if it is possible to have the proxy trap be coded to erase the JavaScript object before the object can be manipulated. Thank you

Comment: It is my hope to find a solution for how transparent the DOM is, and how one can add in new elements to do anything with. If by attempting to do anything in JavaScript one trips this trap -first-, it could secure things up just that much more. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting can't really be done. You CAN create a proxy to trap retrieval/manipulation calls but you can't make the underlying object private in any way.

For example, if you have object

```
const privateObj = { name: 'John Smith', ssn: '123-45-6789' };
```

and proxy

```
const proxy = new Proxy(privateObj, {} /* handler for getter/setter traps */);
```

you can console log the proxy to get something like this:

```
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

and you can expand `[[Target]]` to see the properties of the underlying object. So if you want this property to be fully private you won't want to use proxies. Furthermore, if the user can inspect the proxy, they can easily get access to the underlying object and mutate it outside of the proxy traps.

If you want to be able to really protect that object, it would be better to protect it in a function closure and have getter/setter wrappers around that object.

You could try as a first step:

```
const protectObject = (SessionKey, ...objectProps) => {
    const protectedObject = { // Do something here to create the object
        ...objectProps        // and its properties you want to protect
    };

    return {
        accessProp(_SessionKey, prop) {
            if (_SessionKey !== SessionKey) throw Error("Your session key doesn't match");
            return protectedObject[prop];
        },
        setProp(_SessionKey, prop, val) {
            if (_SessionKey !== SessionKey) throw Error("Your session key doesn't match");
            protectedObject[prop] = val;
        }
    };
};
```

So now you have a private object that is protected:

```
const privateObj = protectObject('12345', 'John Smith', '7/20/1992', '123-45-6789');

privateObj.accessProp('12345', 1); // '7/20/1992'
privateObj.accessProp('1234', 2);  // Uncaught Error: Your session key doesn't match
privateObj.setProp('12345', 1, '7/21/1993');
privateObj.accessProp('12345', 1); // '7/21/1993'
```